# How to maintain a Map<EntityA, EntityB> in JPA2?

Tags: jpa, dictionary, entity, jpa-2.0, one-to-many

I have three entity classes (*A*, *B*, *C*). *A* should contain a map which maps instances of *B* to instances of *C*. All instances of *C* are owned by a map of some *A*. I've tried this (getters and setters omitted):

```
@Entity public class A {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

  // I want to map this in an elegant way:
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="a") @MapKey(name="b") private Map<B, C> map;
}

@Entity public class B {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
}

@Entity public class C {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

  // I don't really want the following in Java, unidirectional access from A to C would suffice:
  @ManyToOne private A a;
  @ManyToOne private B b;
  // Can I get rid of a and b?
}
```

That gives a nice schema (exactly the one that I want!), but in Java there's ugly duplication given that there are now *two* ways to specify the relation:

```
a.map.put(b, c);
```

and

```
c.a = a;
c.b = b;
```

What happens if I just change one half of the association? That looks problematic. What is the best way around that? Isn't there some more elegant solution for the required unidirectional access?

I considered making *C* @Embeddable and use an @ElementCollection for *A.map*, but in reality *C* is an abstract base class for different entities which means that it can't be made @Embeddable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of schema do you want, but you can use [`@MapKeyJoinColumn`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) to make this relationship unidirectional, see example 1 in javadoc.